# ConTeXt : defining specific behavior with mode

Tags: conditionals, context

I'm trying to define my own start/stop block, for a conditional compilation with some formatting. I tried to use modes and add a margin rule if the block is to be shown.

However, it compiles correctly only if the mode is enabled. If the mode is disabled, the compilation does not work. Here is my MWE :

```
\definemode[teacherversion][yes]
\definestartstop[teacheronly]
                [before={\startmode[teacherversion]\startmarginrule},
                after={\stopmarginrule\stopmode}]
\disablemode[teacherversion]
\starttext
Text before

\startteacheronly
  \input knuth
\stopteacheronly

Text after
\stoptext
```

and the output of context :

```
adrien@arsenalGear:~/dev/testConteXt$ context blocktest.tex

mtx-context     | run 1: luatex --fmt="/opt/context/tex/texmf-cache/luatex-cache/context/5fe67e0bfe781ce0dde776fb1556f32e/formats/luatex/cont-en" --jobname="blocktest" --lua="/opt/context/tex/texmf-cache/luatex-cache/context/5fe67e0bfe781ce0dde776fb1556f32e/formats/luatex/cont-en.lui" --no-parse-first-line --c:currentrun=1 --c:fulljobname="./blocktest.tex" --c:input="./blocktest.tex" --c:kindofrun=1 --c:maxnofruns=9 "cont-yes.mkiv"
This is LuaTeX, Version 0.95.0 (TeX Live 2016) 
 system commands enabled.
open source     > 1 > 1 > /opt/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/mkiv/cont-yes.mkiv

ConTeXt  ver: 2016.07.08 17:19 MKIV beta  fmt: 2016.7.9  int: english/english

system          > 'cont-new.mkiv' loaded
open source     > 2 > 2 > /opt/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/mkiv/cont-new.mkiv
close source    > 2 > 2 > /opt/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/mkiv/cont-new.mkiv
system          > files > jobname 'blocktest', input './blocktest', result 'blocktest'
fonts           > latin modern fonts are not preloaded
languages       > language 'en' is active
open source     > 2 > 3 > /home/adrien/dev/testConteXt/blocktest.tex
fonts           > preloading latin modern fonts (second stage)
fonts           > 'fallback modern-designsize rm 12pt' is loaded
close source    > 2 > 3 > /home/adrien/dev/testConteXt/blocktest.tex
close source    > 1 > 3 > /opt/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/mkiv/cont-yes.mkiv

*
```

The star is a prompt. How can I achieve my conditional compilation please ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you disable the `teacherversion` mode the `\startmode` command tries to gobble everything until `\stopmode` which doesn’t work when you embed them into other commands. What you have to is to create first your `teacheronly` environment to ensure the commands exist and put the setups the enable margin rule in a separate `mode` block.

```
\definemode[teacherversion][yes]

%\disablemode[teacherversion]

\definestartstop[teacheronly]

\startmode[teacherversion]
  \setupstartstop
    [teacheronly]
    [before=\startmarginrule,
     after=\stopmarginrule]
\stopmode

\starttext

Text before

\startteacheronly
  \input knuth
\stopteacheronly

Text after

\stoptext
```

When you want to gobble the complete content of the `teacheronly` environment you can create to different definitions.

```
\definemode[teacherversion][yes]

%\disablemode[teacherversion]

\startmode[teacherversion]
  \definestartstop
    [teacheronly]
    [before=\startmarginrule,
     after=\stopmarginrule]
\stopmode

\startnotmode[teacherversion]
  \definebuffer[teacheronly]
\stopnotmode

\starttext

Text before

\startteacheronly
  \input knuth
\stopteacheronly

Text after

\stoptext
```

For both method above you the enable/disable the mode before the content them is set, to get rid of this limitation the following solution can be used which checks the mode before it flushes the stored content.

```
\definemode[teacherversion][yes]

\definebuffer[teacheronly]

\def\stopteacheronly
  {\doifmode{teacherversion}
     {\startmarginrule
      \getdefinedbuffer[teacheronly]
      \stopmarginrule}}

%\disablemode[teacherversion]

\starttext

Text before

\startteacheronly
  \input knuth
\stopteacheronly

Text after

\stoptext
```

Comment: I actually want the content of teacheronly to be skipped when the mode teacherversion is disabled. I just tried your second solution, but the content (and the marginrule) appears even when I use \disablemode[teacherversion] just before \starttext. Is there any reason for this behavior ?

Comment: @A.Licari I added a third method which lets you enable/disable the mode at any point in your document.