# Top-Level content between items in ConTeXt

Tags: context, itemize, context-mkiv

Suppose I have

```
\starttext
\startitemize[a]
  \item Some task to do

  \startmode[solution]
    Proposed solution
  \stopmode

  \item Some other task
  ...
\stopitemize
\stoptext
```

I want to have the solution rendered at top level (i.e. not indented like the item content), but I also want to continue the item labeling (so simply dropping out of `itemize` and later open it anew doesn't work, because it would start at `a.` again).

The first thing I found is the `indentnext` property, which should not indent following paragraphs of an item. I tried both of these things, but none worked:

```
\setupitemgroup[itemize][nextindent=no]
\startitemize[a]
```

and:

```
\startitemize[a][nextindent=no]
```

The solution was still indented. This should work according to the wiki, but I could not figure out how. Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the solution with `continue` surely works, I don't think it is really along »the ConTeXt way«.  I would go to higher abstraction and create tailored environments for exercises and solutions.

```
\defineenumeration
  [exercise]
  [
    text=,
    alternative=left,
    numberconversion=a,
    headstyle=,
    stopper=.,
    width=fit,
  ]

% You cannot wrap modes into \start...\stop
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/319269/10995
\startmode[solution]
  \definestartstop[solution]
\stopmode

\startnotmode[solution]
  \definebuffer[solution]
\stopnotmode

\starttext

\startexercise
  \input knuth
\stopexercise

\startsolution
  \input ward
\stopsolution

\startexercise
  \input zapf
\stopexercise

\stoptext
```

The screenshot is typeset with `solution` mode enabled.

[image]

Comment: This is a good solution. However, it changes the way the exercises are rendered (not indenting the whole paragraph after **a**). So I will go the middle way: using `\startexercise` but mapping it to `\startitemize[a]` with or without `continue` conditionally.

Comment: @flyx Oh, just choose `alternative=hanging` or `left` instead of `serried`.

Answer (score 5):

Use the "`continue`" keyword to `\startitemize`:

```
\starttext
\startitemize[a]
  \item Some task to do
\stopitemize

\startmode[solution]
  Proposed solution
\stopmode

\startitemize[a,continue]
  \item Some other task
  ...
\stopitemize

\stoptext
```

Comment: While this solution worked well for a while, it broke once the solution also includes `\startitemize` because then, the `continue` would continue at the counter of the itemize in the solution.