# ConTeXt: using modes to extract only parts of a document

Tags: context

In ConTeXt, is it possible to use modes to extract only parts of a document, say only the exercises?

My naive try was

```
\defineenumeration[exercise][
before={\startmode[Quest]\blank[line]},
after={\blank[line]\stopmode},
]

\starttext
\input knuth
\startexercise
\input tufte
\stopexercise
\input knuth
\stoptext
```

but that does not even compile. What I would ultimately like to have:

Running `context file.tex` I get the full document.

Running `context --mode=Quest file.tex` I get only the exercises (that are defined in the enumeration exercise).

I would also like, if possible, not have to type `\startmode` and `\stopmode` at every instance where the exercises appear.

Comment: What about puting the definition inside `\startmode`?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I dont see how that helps me to get what I'm after. Maybe I just dont see how modes work.

Comment: [Here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/333929/21930) you have an answer from Henri Menke.

Comment: Thank you for the link. Now at last I know that it is not possible to do it with before and after. Also, this shows how to hide the exercises. I dont see how to hide everything but the exeecises. But it is getting closer.

Comment: I don't think ConTeXt (or any other variant of TeX) can do what you want. A mode can show or hide parts of a document. Your requirements amount to filtering part of your document when a mode is enabled (hiding all the rest). It's relatively straightforward to come up with a solution in xml, processed by ConTeXt. But if you want to write your document in ConTeXt syntax, I don't see how this is possible.

Comment: Thank you @Thomas for your comment. Since this might be impossible, I simply wrote an email to the list asking the same question. I will get back here if/when I get a solution or a confirmation that it is not possible.

Comment: See [this mail from Wolfgang](https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2016/087494.html) on the ConTeXt mailing list for a suggestion on how this could be implemented. At this point I'm waiting to see if it will be implemented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mind modifying your source file a little bit, here is a solution using the `translate` module.

```
\defineenumeration[exercise]
\usemodule[translate]
\translateinput[startexercise][stopnotmode\startexercise]
\translateinput[stopexercise][{stopexercise\startnotmode[question]}]
\enableinputtranslation


\starttext\startnotmode[question]
Random text
\startexercise
  Content of exercise 1
\stopexercise
More random text
\startexercise
  Content of exercise 2
\stopexercise
More random text
\stopnotmode\stoptext
```

Note that I have replaced `\starttext` with `\starttext\startnotmode[question]` and `\stoptext` with `\stopnotmode\stoptext`.

When you compile the file using `context test.tex`, then the output is:

[image]

When you compile using `context --mode=question test.tex`, then the output is:

[image]

Comment: Sorry for being slow. This is a very nice trick! When I first saw your example I did not think it would work with references or titles (of the exercise), but it does! This is an acceptable solution for me (I will not have to change a lot of code, but only some parts of the "pramble"), so I will accept your answer.